# SQL Server : using a user-defined column in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For example, I have

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([Path], 0, 5) AS [Directory]
      , COUNT([Directory])
FROM [MyDatabase]
GROUP BY [Directory];
```

But I get an "Invalid column name" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([Path], 0, 5) AS [Directory]
      , COUNT(1)
FROM [MyDatabase]
GROUP BY SUBSTRING([Path], 0, 5);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure this is something you could find on google but I couldn't get it to stop returning only stuff about user defined aggregate functions.

Comment: @user2476260 - np, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is the alias in column name used in count(), I also don't see why two columns are needed when it just takes the count. Try

```
SELECT COUNT(SUBSTRING([Path], 0, 5))      
    FROM [MyDatabase];
```

If you need both columns, then here:

```
   SELECT SUBSTRING([Path], 0, 5) AS [Directory]
  , COUNT(SUBSTRING([Path], 0, 5) )
   FROM [MyDatabase]
   GROUP BY SUBSTRING([Path], 0, 5);
```

Comment: I need the substring as well. It's part of a larger query.

Comment: i see. I re-wrote it. paste the 2nd query and try.